# No query results for model [App\Products] Laravel 5.2

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5

I have a table "Food" which has a column Food_id that a food Id of each food. I want to show the foods according to Food_id.

**My Controller is:**

```
public function index()

{

$details= Food::all();

return view('details.index', compact('details'));

}

public function show($Food_id)

{

 $detail=Food::findOrFail($Food_id);

 return view('details.show', compact('detail'));

}
```

**My routes are:**

```
Route::get('details', 'DetailsController@index');

Route::get('details/{Food_id}', 'DetailsController@show');
```

**index.blade.php:**

```
 @extends('layouts.app')

 @section('content')

 <h1>Details</h1>

 <hr/>  


 @foreach($details as $detail)

 <detail>

<h2>

    <a href="/details/{{$detail->Food_id}}">{{$detail->FoodName}}
    </a>

</h2>

 </detail>

 @endforeach

 @endsection
```

**show.blade.php:**

```
 <h1 align="center">{{$detail -> FoodName}}</h1>

 <detail>

 <h3><p>FoodType:</h3><h4>{{$detail->FoodType}}</h4></p>
```

AND **welcome.blade.php:**

> ```
> <button type="submit" onclick="window.location='http://localhost:8000/details'"  
>                         style="font-size:14px; width: 230px; height: 30px; background-color: #00A30C; color: white; font-style: italic; text-align: center; font-size: 15px; margin: 0 auto;">
>                         {{ $Food[$i]->FoodName }}          
>                         <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right"></i></button>
> ```

My problem is that I have a button with image of food on welcomepage and I want that when I click the button,it shows me the food details based on food_id. When I click on button from welcomepage it shows me the details page where again all food items are shown as shown in screen:

[image]

Then by clicking on any food items it shows me datails of food as:

[image]

But I want that when I click food item from welcome page it shows me this page without showing screen 1 page.

Comment: onclick="window.location='http://localhost:8000/details'"

Comment: Are you able to get `$Food_id` in `show($Food_id)` function ?

Comment: @Abbasi yes I am able to get $Food_id in show function

Comment: probably, check your `layouts.app` and other `blades` that you are not including index.blade twice

Comment: @Abbasi I include layout.app on all pages but not mention here,i told my problem with screenshots,the only problem is I don't want the details page in the mid.

Comment: so that directly from welcomepage on clicking any food item button it redirects me to page like screen2 based on Food_id

Comment: Yes that what I see, and what I understand is that you want to grid rid of food list from detail page as in above screenshot, right? if so then I suspect you are adding contents of welcome page twice somewhere in blade. That was my point to check blades and layout.

Comment: all the blade files are correct,there is some other issue.The function onclick="window.location='localhost:8000/details'" is correct?beacuse this page leads to details page.can we add something after 'localhost:8000/details' to directly shows the details of foods?

Comment: can you please update your question with step by step screenshots and code because I can't get it why `onclick="window.location='http://localhost:8000/details'"` is there.

Comment: I have already posted the whole code and screenshots